# jquery html() -> TypeError: this[0].innerHTML is undefined

Tags: jquery

I have an element:

`var node = $(xml).find('target');`

node is something like `<content><item><target>Breadcrumbs</target></item>
</content>`. So node is actually an ***xml*** element

And I want to strip the `<content>` node, but keep everything else.

I thought `$(node).html()` would work . but I get an error.
Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: It' an element that I get from doing $(html).find('target');

Comment: Your code seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/dvNPE/

Comment: Your code should work.  Please show a complete failing example.  (the act of doing so may solve your problem)

Comment: For the sake of any Googlers, try this answer by bobince: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037073/jquery-xml-parsing-replacing-tags

Answer (score 1):

This works when you add quotes to the string:

```
var node = "<content><item><target>Breadcrumbs</target></item> </content>";
alert($(node).html());
```

Result:

```
<item><target>Breadcrumbs</target></item>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hEtgH/

Assuming your node actually is pulled out of the dom, it would be similar.

```
<content id="blah"><item><target>Breadcrumbs</target></item> </content>
```

Then:

```
alert($("#blah").html());
```

Result:

```
<item><target>Breadcrumbs</target></item>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YrLfu/

Comment: Not really an answer, since you didn't change anything. :-)

Comment: I added quotes to the string assuming that was what was missing.

Comment: Ok but how do I turn my node into a string, because the element is a dom element, not a string

Comment: The above code actually is converting the string into a node then getting its contents. We need to know more about node to answer.

Comment: Added example of pulling content from the dom.

Comment: +1; Very interesting and good solution. wonder how the first tag `<content>` is not coming using `.html()`??

Comment: Because `content` is the top level node and .html() selects it's children.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with jquery and ie, when trying to get html() for an element. Reason is that xml Element does not define innerHTML in IE.

I found a temporary solution with innerXHTML code here:

http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/page-innerxhtml.php

It allows you to send the element to a function with name innerXHTML and return valid html.